# Shot Javascript <script></script> not in TextArea

Tags: javascript, textbox

I have a piece of code in Javascript to detect the resoultion of the screen.
Now the results for me(1920 x 1080) are standing inside a textbox (input) but I just want it without textbox. How do i need to do this?

Code:

```
<head>

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    function scrResolution() {
        var width = screen.width;
        var height = screen.height;
        document.getElementById("txt_scrWidth").value = width;
        document.getElementById("txt_scrHeight").value = height;
    }
</script>
    </head>


<body onload="scrResolution();">
  <table width="200" border="0">
     <tr>
       <td>  
 Width :
<input name="txt_scrWidth" type="text" id="txt_scrWidth" size="5" />
      </td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
       <td>
           Height :  
 <input name="txt_scrHeight" type="text" id="txt_scrHeight" size="5" />
       </td>
     </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I do not see a textarea here..

Comment: @darma I guess he means the `input`s

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "standing inside a text area", do you mean that the values are showing inside of your inputs?

Comment: If you want it without the textboxes, in what way do you want it? What is it that you are going to use it for?

Comment: i mean the input fields, i just wanted them on my screen just as string text without any kind of area

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<head>

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    function scrResolution() {
        var width = screen.width;
        var height = screen.height;
        document.getElementById("txt_scrWidth").innerHTML = width;
        document.getElementById("txt_scrHeight").innerHTML= height;
    }
</script>
    </head>


<body onload="scrResolution();">
  <table width="200" border="0">
     <tr>
       <td>  
 Width : <span id="txt_scrWidth"></span>
      </td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
       <td>
           Height :  <span id="txt_scrHeight"></span>  
       </td>
     </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe try adding a `span` instead:

```
<table width="200" border="0">
    <tr>
        <td>Width: <span id="txt_scrWidth"></span></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
         <td>Height: <span id="txt_scrHeight"></span></td>
     </tr>
</table>
```

And then set `innerHTML` using JavaScript:

```
function scrResolution()
{
    var width = screen.width;
    var height = screen.height;
    document.getElementById("txt_scrWidth").innerHTML = width;
    document.getElementById("txt_scrHeight").innerHTML  = height;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are working on a web application, you may be more interested in the size of the browser window's viewport. Here is how you would get that information. The onresize listener will make sue that it is updated if the user changes the screen size.

Here is the script

```
<script>
//make sure we update if the user resizes the browser
window.onresize = function() {
    showSize();   
};

function showSize() {
    document.getElementById("heightDisplay").innerHTML = document.height;
    document.getElementById("widthDisplay").innerHTML = document.width;
}

showSize();
</script>
```

Here's the HTML

```
<div>
    Height: <span id="heightDisplay">Calculating...</span><br/>
    Width: <span id="widthDisplay">Calculating...</span>
</div>
```